# Как сохранить состояние бина и загрузить при обращении к нему? JSF

Tags: веб-программирование, java-ee, jsf

`@ViewScoped` - Бин живёт до тех пор, пока пользователь взаимодействует с JSF представлением в браузере или окне. Создаётся в момент HTTP – запроса и уничтожается после того, как пользователь переходит к другому JSF представлению (например, на другую страницу).

Хотелось бы перед уничтожением бина сохранить его состояние, и, при последующем обращении к бину, подгрузить его, можно ли это как-нибудь сделать?

Comment: Выглядит как разбухание логики web-слоя и повод использовать ejb+jpa.

Comment: Вы описываете жизненный цикл @SessionScoped. Если он Вам не подходит, то других готовых вариантов нет - придётся реализовывать сохранение/восстановление самостоятельно